# How to access the content of a map and process it in java?

Tags: java

I’m reading access logs files and grouping by IP and storing it in a map. At the end I get each IP as the key and the values are the date and urls. I’m storing the values as a list.

```
HashMap<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

The result:

```
IP: 46.33.8.38 ==> [[16/Jul/2011:12:25:23, /TestWebPages/index.html], [16/Jul/2011:12:25:46, /TestWebPages/MScAIS-SEWN-Search-Optimisation.html], [16/Jul/2011:12:25:46, /TestWebPages/valid-rss-rogers.png]]
…
```

Now I would like to further group the content of the map depending on the day and time. But I don’t know how can I access the list of each key in the map and process it!

So I would like to have those webpages accessed on the same day associated with IP address in a new map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over a map, use code like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    List<String> valueList = entry.getValue();
    for (String value : valueList) {
        // Do something with value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about just getting the list by a key as oppose to printing it out:

```
List<String> data = map.get("46.33.8.38");
for(String str : data) {
    //Do what you like with each string here
}
```

Or if you mean you want to get all the values in the map, `entrySet()` is your friend:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    for(String str : entry.getValue()) {
        //Do what you like with each string here
    }
}
```

If you're talking about accessing the values in the map using multiple keys (so it's keyed on date, time, etc. as well as IP address) the simplest solution is probably to create multiple maps containing the same values but each working on a different key.